# Use vidalia bandwidth graph with TBB

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, vidalia

I use Tor browser bundle, I wish to see Vidalia's Tor Bandwidth usage graph of Tor traffic from my browser bundle.

How can install vidalia on Tor browser bundle to see this graph?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get installation file of vidalia from the following site:

https://people.torproject.org/~erinn/vidalia-standalone-bundles/

You have to first run the TBB and then vidalia to see the graph.

Comment: Note! This answer is no longer accurate. The answer now is that Vidalia is obsolete and unmaintained, and you should not try to use it with your Tor Browser.